# Jquery Plugin Customization regarding $.fn.variable_name

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am new to Jquery.I found a code line like,

```
$.fn.variable_name={ 
        function_name1:{//function body goes here},
        function_name2:{//function body goes here},...
 };
```

Please help me What its means.I know how to create functions using **$.fn**

```
$.fn.function_name={ 
            //function body goes here
     };
```

But have no idea about the first code.I don't know how stupid this question is.Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

As explained in your other question, this is called as jquery plugin and this should be used with the Dom element to add more features, events and methods to the element. For an instance, if you want to convert the text box as date picker (calendar) you can create a plugin of your own or extend any existing plugin to add more features. Also with $.widget which is an advanced one than the plugins, you can do more awesome widgets and animations. Hope you understood.